# Slide div up before sliding next div down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I am using the "super simple JQuery content swapper." I would use one with these animation options already built in, but I am also using a slider, and it appears that script and the slider script are incompatible. This one seems to work, but the issue I'm having is that the first div and the next div open and close at the same time.

I would like a slideUp, then slideDown effect, but whatever I try results in the same thing: slideUp and slideDown at the same time. I admit I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery, so this might be a simple solution I am not seeing. Sorry in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Webpage</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    function contentSwitcher(settings){
        var settings = {
           contentClass : '.content',
           navigationId : '#navigation'
        };

        //Hide all of the content except the first one on the nav
        $(settings.contentClass).not(':first').hide();
        $(settings.navigationId).find('li:first').addClass('active');

        //onClick set the active state, 
        //hide the content panels and show the correct one
        $(settings.navigationId).find('a').click(function(e){
            var contentToShow = $(this).attr('href');
            contentToShow = $(contentToShow);

            //dissable normal link behaviour
            e.preventDefault();

            //set the proper active class for active state css
            $(settings.navigationId).find('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

            //hide the old content and show the new
            $(settings.contentClass).slideUp();
              contentToShow.slideDown();
        });
    }
    contentSwitcher();
});
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" />
    <style type="text/css">

#navigation {
    position: fixed; left: 100px; top: 0px; right: 100px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: auto; height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: ; font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    }

#gallery {
    }

#gallery img {
    width: auto; height: 250px;
    }

#about {
    position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100px; right: 0px; bottom: 75px;
    width: 100%; height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    }

#contact {
    position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100px; right: 0px; bottom: 75px;
    width: 100%; height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    color: #fff;
    }


    </style>    

</head>
<body>


<div id="navigation"><ul><li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li><li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li><li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li></ul></div>
<div id="gallery" class="content"><div class="owl-carousel"><a class="item" href="" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
<a class="item" href="" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
<a class="item" href="" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
<a class="item" href="" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="" alt="" /></a></div></div>
<div id="about" class="content">About</div>
<div id="contact" class="content">Contact</div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {    
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
         items: 3,
         loop: true,
         margin: 10,
         center: true,
         responsive: {
                600:{
                    items: 4
                }
            }
     });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Despite all the excellent suggestions, it acts funny when I try to implement them. Maybe it's not compatible with my coding, or other JavaScripts? Here is the full thing, I hope it helps.

Comment: Try placing the `slideDown()` method inside the `complete` setting of the `slideUp()` method

Comment: It still acted a little funny. I included the entire code, maybe there's something that's interacting with it?

Comment: You may try to included the `slideDown()` inside a `setTimeout()` method to give some time to the `slideUp()` to finish its animation

Answer (score 2):

call slideDown as a callback from the first animation

```
$(settings.contentClass).slideUp('fast', function () {
    contentToShow.slideDown();
});
```

Comment: That's what I found when looking around, but it doesn't seem to work with my code for some reason. It acts a little funny...

Comment: hmm you will need to include a speed if doing it this way, or you could do slideUp({
  complete: function () {
    contentToShow.slideDown();
  }
})

Comment: Still acting funny... I included the entire code, I hope it helps some more.